# Using Anaconda prompt to open and create .py files with Spyder

Tags: python, command-line, anaconda3

I have gotten very used to using the terminal to open VS code and create an empty python  file with the command:
`code filename.py`

I'm currently using the anaconda prompt in a virtual environment with only spyder installed as my IDE. Is there a command in the anaconda prompt that will give me the functionality of opening a blank Spyder file pointing to the current working directory?

Comment: how about `spyder filename.py`